# Matching Coordinate Pairs to Countries (Large Scale)

Tags: csv, match, coordinates, country, large-data

I've seen previous discussions about finding a country based on longitude and latitude coordinates which have led to a couple useful links.

http://www.worldatlas.com/aatlas/latitude_and_longitude_finder.htm

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse

are two examples.

My problem is that I have a long list of coordinate pairs (26,400 pairs to be exact) and obviously don't have time to search each one individually.  Is there a way I can automatically search all of my coordinate pairs, which are stored in a .csv file?

Comment: What OS are you on? Mac OSX? Linux? Windows?

Comment: Mac OSX or Windows. My Windows machine is faster, but I can use whichever is easier/better.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your CSV looks like this:

```
51.23,2.34
52.5,-1.8
54.88,-3.2
```

you can read it line by line and have Google geocode it for you with this

```
while IFS="," read lat lon
do

   country=$(curl "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=$lat,$lon&sensor=false" | xmlstarlet sel -t -v '/GeocodeResponse/result/address_component[type="country"]/long_name' | head -1)
   echo $lat,$lon,$country
   sleep 10
done < file.csv
```

There are limits to how many lookups you can do in a day (please check and observe) so that is why I have added a `sleep` in there. Alternatively, you can change the word `xml` in the `curl` request to `json` and you will get the result in JSON format for parsing.

If you want to test this out, just paste the parameter to `curl` into your browser address bar without the double quotes, and you will see what you get returned:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GeocodeResponse>
 <status>OK</status>
 <result>
  <type>route</type>
  <formatted_address>A303, Salisbury, Wiltshire SP4 7DE, UK</formatted_address>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>A303</long_name>
   <short_name>A303</short_name>
   <type>route</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Salisbury</long_name>
   <short_name>Salisbury</short_name>
   <type>postal_town</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Wiltshire</long_name>
   <short_name>Wiltshire</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_2</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>United Kingdom</long_name>                <----- Here it is!
   <short_name>GB</short_name>
   <type>country</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>SP4 7DE</long_name>
   <short_name>SP4 7DE</short_name>
   <type>postal_code</type>
  </address_component>
  <geometry>
   <location>
    <lat>51.1771403</lat>
    <lng>-1.8236094</lng>
   </location>
   <location_type>APPROXIMATE</location_type>
   <viewport>
    <southwest>
     <lat>51.1757619</lat>
     <lng>-1.8272403</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>51.1784599</lat>
     <lng>-1.8199612</lng>
    </northeast>
   </viewport>
   <bounds>
    <southwest>
     <lat>51.1766085</lat>
     <lng>-1.8272403</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>51.1776133</lat>
     <lng>-1.8199612</lng>
    </northeast>
   </bounds>
  </geometry>
  <place_id>ChIJcWNIljzmc0gROJ_DtvMZDew</place_id>
 </result>
 <result>
  <type>postal_code</type>
  <formatted_address>Salisbury, Wiltshire SP4 7DE, UK</formatted_address>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>SP4 7DE</long_name>
   <short_name>SP4 7DE</short_name>
   <type>postal_code</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Salisbury</long_name>
   <short_name>Salisbury</short_name>
   <type>postal_town</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Wiltshire</long_name>
   <short_name>Wiltshire</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_2</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>United Kingdom</long_name>
   <short_name>GB</short_name>
   <type>country</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <geometry>
   <location>
    <lat>51.1802192</lat>
    <lng>-1.8270873</lng>
   </location>
   <location_type>APPROXIMATE</location_type>
   <viewport>
    <southwest>
     <lat>51.1658495</lat>
     <lng>-1.8606635</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>51.1865446</lat>
     <lng>-1.8147963</lng>
    </northeast>
   </viewport>
   <bounds>
    <southwest>
     <lat>51.1658495</lat>
     <lng>-1.8606635</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>51.1865446</lat>
     <lng>-1.8147963</lng>
    </northeast>
   </bounds>
  </geometry>
  <place_id>ChIJ58eYzzvmc0gR-x4igRCCDgI</place_id>
 </result>
 <result>
  <type>administrative_area_level_4</type>
  <type>political</type>
  <formatted_address>Amesbury, Wiltshire, UK</formatted_address>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Amesbury</long_name>
   <short_name>Amesbury</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_4</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Wiltshire</long_name>
   <short_name>Wiltshire</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_2</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>England</long_name>
   <short_name>England</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>United Kingdom</long_name>
   <short_name>GB</short_name>
   <type>country</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <geometry>
   <location>
    <lat>51.1749580</lat>
    <lng>-1.7790983</lng>
   </location>
   <location_type>APPROXIMATE</location_type>
   <viewport>
    <southwest>
     <lat>51.1494527</lat>
     <lng>-1.8535583</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>51.1919313</lat>
     <lng>-1.7117001</lng>
    </northeast>
   </viewport>
   <bounds>
    <southwest>
     <lat>51.1494527</lat>
     <lng>-1.8535583</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>51.1919313</lat>
     <lng>-1.7117001</lng>
    </northeast>
   </bounds>
  </geometry>
  <place_id>ChIJMxey-_nlc0gRfdhQ9YfIO7A</place_id>
 </result>
 <result>
  <type>postal_code_prefix</type>
  <type>postal_code</type>
  <formatted_address>SP4, United Kingdom</formatted_address>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>SP4</long_name>
   <short_name>SP4</short_name>
   <type>postal_code_prefix</type>
   <type>postal_code</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>United Kingdom</long_name>
   <short_name>GB</short_name>
   <type>country</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <geometry>
   <location>
    <lat>51.1870058</lat>
    <lng>-1.7711005</lng>
   </location>
   <location_type>APPROXIMATE</location_type>
   <viewport>
    <southwest>
     <lat>51.0708387</lat>
     <lng>-1.8606635</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>51.2759513</lat>
     <lng>-1.6287743</lng>
    </northeast>
   </viewport>
   <bounds>
    <southwest>
     <lat>51.0708387</lat>
     <lng>-1.8606635</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>51.2759513</lat>
     <lng>-1.6287743</lng>
    </northeast>
   </bounds>
  </geometry>
  <place_id>ChIJ4dSKGIjjc0gRQoURkIFH8Ww</place_id>
 </result>
 <result>
  <type>postal_town</type>
  <formatted_address>Salisbury, UK</formatted_address>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Salisbury</long_name>
   <short_name>Salisbury</short_name>
   <type>postal_town</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>United Kingdom</long_name>
   <short_name>GB</short_name>
   <type>country</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <geometry>
   <location>
    <lat>51.1232079</lat>
    <lng>-1.8390956</lng>
   </location>
   <location_type>APPROXIMATE</location_type>
   <viewport>
    <southwest>
     <lat>50.9187178</lat>
     <lng>-2.2108535</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>51.2759513</lat>
     <lng>-1.5617645</lng>
    </northeast>
   </viewport>
   <bounds>
    <southwest>
     <lat>50.9187178</lat>
     <lng>-2.2108535</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>51.2759513</lat>
     <lng>-1.5617645</lng>
    </northeast>
   </bounds>
  </geometry>
  <place_id>ChIJy0okEgrCc0gRCVJTyWezH-k</place_id>
 </result>
 <result>
  <type>administrative_area_level_2</type>
  <type>political</type>
  <formatted_address>Wiltshire, UK</formatted_address>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>Wiltshire</long_name>
   <short_name>Wiltshire</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_2</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>England</long_name>
   <short_name>England</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>United Kingdom</long_name>
   <short_name>GB</short_name>
   <type>country</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <geometry>
   <location>
    <lat>51.2462714</lat>
    <lng>-1.9922127</lng>
   </location>
   <location_type>APPROXIMATE</location_type>
   <viewport>
    <southwest>
     <lat>50.9449920</lat>
     <lng>-2.3655985</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>51.7031417</lat>
     <lng>-1.4857261</lng>
    </northeast>
   </viewport>
   <bounds>
    <southwest>
     <lat>50.9449920</lat>
     <lng>-2.3655985</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>51.7031417</lat>
     <lng>-1.4857261</lng>
    </northeast>
   </bounds>
  </geometry>
  <place_id>ChIJKcgiicI3cUgRNJe9kfg0iGQ</place_id>
 </result>
 <result>
  <type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
  <type>political</type>
  <formatted_address>England, UK</formatted_address>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>England</long_name>
   <short_name>England</short_name>
   <type>administrative_area_level_1</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>United Kingdom</long_name>
   <short_name>GB</short_name>
   <type>country</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <geometry>
   <location>
    <lat>52.3555177</lat>
    <lng>-1.1743197</lng>
   </location>
   <location_type>APPROXIMATE</location_type>
   <viewport>
    <southwest>
     <lat>49.9588004</lat>
     <lng>-5.7169817</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>55.8111127</lat>
     <lng>1.7629159</lng>
    </northeast>
   </viewport>
   <bounds>
    <southwest>
     <lat>49.8647517</lat>
     <lng>-6.4177822</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>55.8111127</lat>
     <lng>1.7629159</lng>
    </northeast>
   </bounds>
  </geometry>
  <place_id>ChIJ39UebIqp0EcRqI4tMyWV4fQ</place_id>
 </result>
 <result>
  <type>country</type>
  <type>political</type>
  <formatted_address>United Kingdom</formatted_address>
  <address_component>
   <long_name>United Kingdom</long_name>
   <short_name>GB</short_name>
   <type>country</type>
   <type>political</type>
  </address_component>
  <geometry>
   <location>
    <lat>54.9713902</lat>
    <lng>-2.7427767</lng>
   </location>
   <location_type>APPROXIMATE</location_type>
   <viewport>
    <southwest>
     <lat>49.8669688</lat>
     <lng>-8.6493572</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>60.8565530</lat>
     <lng>1.7627096</lng>
    </northeast>
   </viewport>
   <bounds>
    <southwest>
     <lat>34.5625145</lat>
     <lng>-8.6493572</lng>
    </southwest>
    <northeast>
     <lat>60.9023960</lat>
     <lng>33.9165550</lng>
    </northeast>
   </bounds>
  </geometry>
  <place_id>ChIJqZHHQhE7WgIReiWIMkOg-MQ</place_id>
 </result>
</GeocodeResponse>
```

There are other geocoding services, with different capabilities and restrictions, available - Geonames springs to mind.